# PHP: Get session variables from a resumed session

Tags: php

I have a PHP which will be accessible to a bot that does not store any cookies. The session ID can be restored from _POST variables. My understanding is after I resume session from session ID, $_SESSION cannot access session variables in this case because cookies are disabled.

To be precise, the session is started by a user. This PHP page will receive only one POST request from the bot - with the user's session ID passed as parameters. I need to "resume" this session and check what is stored in the user's session.

The bot discards any information sent to it.

Is there any other way to retrieve session variables?

Comment: Is there any reason the bot can't store cookies? Pretty much any scripting language should be able to deal with cookies.

Comment: @GordonBailey It's designed this way. I cannot change the bot.

Comment: Session data is (by default) stored on disk on the server, just the id is sent in the cookie.  Can you not call session_id($_POST['my_sess_id']) and then call session_start()?  That should work ...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way. Utilizing the INI setting `session.use_trans_sid` (set it to "1") will append a query string containing a session ID to all outputted URLs, thus removing the need for cookies.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. To be precise, the session is started by a user. This PHP page will receive only one POST request from the bot - with the user's session ID passed as parameters. I need to "resume" this session and check what is stored in the user's session.

Comment: And the "bot" is very likely to just discard any information sent to it.

Comment: In that case...`session_id($_POST['botsession']);`

Comment: It _does_ work...both scripts are running from the same php.exe/ini combo, right? Also note that you must call session_start _after_ session_id, not before.

Comment: No it doesn't. I found out I had to read the session file and use session_decode to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Many people have suggested to use session_id(...) - this does not work on my setup for some reason. Instead my solution is to read session file and use session_decode(...) to populate $_SESSION variable, then access the variables through $_SESSION.